# How to see the timestamp for when an image was viewed via CLI

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

Can someone confirm if there is a shell tool that can let me see the timestamp of when an image was last viewed? Similar to the stat commands print outs for created and modified?

I'm writing a script that changes folder names on my computer depending on whether the last jpg image in a folder was viewed or not. The way I aimed to do this was to print out the timestamp of when the image was created (using the stat command) and compare that to when the image was last viewed.

I thought when you access an image for viewing, it would change the modify time (which I could then compare) but that doesn't appear to be the case.

I've had a hunt via google and man pages (tools like feh, imagemagik), however I couldn't find something that would show the time I need.

Comment: `stat` shows ctime, mtime, and atime.  atime is the last time the file was accessed.  BTW, ctime is *not* the creation time of the file, and most file systems do not store that attribute.

Comment: @WilliamPursell ... I don't know how I missed that *facepalm* Thanks for the help and the heads up regarding that. I'll try and figure out another approach I can use to make this work.

Comment: If you're using a filesystem that tracks file creation time (Like ext4), the `%w` and `%W` formats for `stat` will display it.

Comment: historically, viewing would modfy the `atime` value but note that often now the default for mount is use `relatime` or `noatime`, in which case the atime value cannot be used reliably for your purpose

Comment: @Shawn thanks. I managed to utilise this approach. The one caveat I did find is that the accessed time only updates once per session, as opposed to updating every time I reopen the file in my current instance. Not ideal but given the first access would change the time, should still meet my needs.